# Where does the information get passed to in a @ControllerAdvice class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling

I have been following a couple of tutorials about error handling using a Spring framework. My handleNullPointer method does catch the null pointer exception. However, I am wondering where the method returns to after that, as I want to display some information of the error on the frontend (a webpage). Here is my GlobalControllerExceptionHandler with the handleNullPointer method (and other implementation attempt of error handling included):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    /* A different attempt at error handling
    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll (Exception exception, WebRequest request) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), "error occured");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }*/

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
    @ResponseBody ErrorInfo
    handleNullPointer(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception){
        System.out.println("This worked.");
        return new ErrorInfo(req.getRequestURL().toString(), exception);
    }
}
```

My idea is that I somehow have to get this information in my javascript on the front end to display the information, but I am new to javascrip. So, I am still unsure if that is the solution I should use.

For reference, here is my ErrorInfo class:

```
public class ErrorInfo {
    public final String url;

    public final String exceptionMessage;

    public ErrorInfo(String url, Exception exception){
        this.url = url;
        this.exceptionMessage = exception.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

Comment: I have read the many related stack overflow questions to this question. However, I do not feel that this is a duplicate. If you feel that it is a duplicate, let me know and I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is pretty much what Spring does for you, and you don't have to manually catch every exception.

E.g. if you do `throw new NullPointerException("Something went wrong");` in any of your controllers, Spring will return a `500` with a response body containing the error message.

You don't mention **how** you send your request, but if you use `fetch` the way to read the response is something like this:

```
fetch("/path/to/resource").then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
    alert(json.error_description);
});
```

which will alert `Something went wrong`;

The only reason I can think of where you'd actually want to catch exceptions the way you propose in your question, is if you want to do something else, like log information about the exception, before returning a response. But in this case you can catch the exception, perform the logging, and then **re-throw it**, and trust Spring to convert this info a proper `500` response.